# C# MVC derived class of HttpPostedFileBase is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am uploading a file in a C# MVC web application using FineUploader. This all works fine when using HttpPostedFileBase as a parameter on the action method:

```
public TextJsonResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase qqfile)
{
    // do some stuff      
}
```

But I want to derive a class from HttpPostedFileBase to override some base properties:

```
public sealed class DerivedHttpPostedFile : HttpPostedFileBase
{
    public override string FileName { get { /* do something different to base() */ }} 
}
```

And use this in the Controller

```
public TextJsonResult SaveFile(DerivedHttpPostedFile qqfile)
{
    // do some stuff      
}
```

But using my derived class in the Controller's action method results in the parameter being null. I'm not sure where I'm gong wrong, as an extensive search of StackOverflow and Google has proved to be fruitless.

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to create your own model binder. I think the default MVC model binder is aware of `HttpPostedFileBase`, but likely it's ignoring your custom class. That's my hunch.

Comment: Using .NET Reflector, I found this class in the ASP.NET MVC binaries `HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder`. You could use the code from that model binder in your custom binder, where you will return an instance of `DerivedHttpPostedFile `. There isn't much code in that model binder, so it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with model binder it won't work keeps on throwing exception.

Debugging thru the source code it seems it's checking against InstanceOfType.

I've posted it at forums.asp.net 
http://forums.asp.net/p/1981337/5674551.aspx?C+MVC+derived+class+of+HttpPostedFileBase+is+null

let's see if something comes up.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post by Hanselman. Essentially you have to create your own model binder for your custom type:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCBetaReleasedCoolnessEnsues.aspx